# What is the meaning of sysname in this suggested create index statement?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Today I ran an query in SSMS and it gave me a hint about a missing index.
But the statement to create the index confuses me, there is the name `Name of Missing Index` which is clear, but there is also `,sysname` in the name part which I dont understand.

I have been going over this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql but I just can't find an explanation on this create syntax.

so in the part `[<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]` can I just replace `Name of Missing Index` and leave the value `sysname` or do I have to put something else there ?

I am  using `sql server 2014`

Here is the result created by SSMS

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery1.sql - SQLSERVER\GTT_192.GTT_Test (sa (70))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 43.2521%.
*/

/*
USE [GTT_Test]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[tblRitRouteDetail] ([DistanceToll])
INCLUDE ([RitID])
GO
*/
```

What is the difference if I would create the index like this :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_RitRouteDetail_DistanceToll  
  ON dbo.tblRitRouteDetail (DistanceToll)  
  INCLUDE (RitID)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sysname` is just the SQL datatype that it is expecting. It is type.sysname, so in essence the command is saying please create an index and the name of the missing index will be of type `sysname`.

> The sysname data type is used for table columns, variables, and stored
> procedure parameters that store object names. The exact definition of
> sysname is related to the rules for identifiers. Therefore, it can
> vary between instances of SQL Server. sysname is functionally the same
> as nvarchar(128) except that, by default, sysname is NOT NULL. In
> earlier versions of SQL Server, sysname is defined as varchar(30).
> Important noteImportant In databases that are case-sensitive, or that
> have a binary collation, sysname is recognized as a SQL Server system
> data type only when it appears in lowercase.
> [msdn reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191240(v=sql.105).aspx)

### Edit

To answer the original question, what is the difference if you create your index one way or the other. There is no difference, they will both create your index in the exact same way.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your index as you have shown it, it will be created and work exactly as expected.
The purpose of the way that it is printed out from SSMS, is to give you a template for the creating of the index.

The first portion on top (below this paragraph) is a comment letting you know where this suggestion came from, and what the expected benefits are:

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery1.sql - SQLSERVER\GTT_192.GTT_Test (sa (70))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 43.2521%.
*/
```

The following section has the index itself with a few parts which you have omitted:
1. It makes sure that you go and use the correct database
it gives you a placeholder for the index name, letting you know what the data type will be (as mentioned by @gh9).
2. all of the schemas, tables, and columns are delimited.
3. batches are marked using the GO keyword

```
/*
USE [GTT_Test]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[tblRitRouteDetail] ([DistanceToll])
INCLUDE ([RitID])
GO
*/
```

As long as you don't by mistake use the incorrect database (for which you provide no check) and don't have a schema/table/column names which are reserved words, or contains a space, you will be ok using your variation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew how to interprete the hint. My question was if there is any difference in creating the index as suggested and my way of creating the index (last statement in the question)

Comment: I explained the difference in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: sorry but I just can't see that explanation. You say I will be ok with my variation, but you don't say what the difference is

Comment: Sure did... there are 3 key differences between your no-frills variation and the one which SSMS printed for you. I expounded on these in between the two code samples. Provided that you don't run into the first two issues, you will be fine.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Your item 1 does tells something about the difference. Your explanation just got a bit lost because you focused alot on not having a check on right database and not using delimiters and the go keyword and so on... which was not the difference I was looking for. I wanted to know the difference in the name part. With our without the sysname. I upped you now

Comment: I see that, appreciate it